# Databse-Server connection to public Internet is unsercure

Tags: database-design

I know that a databse connection to the public internet is a "no-go" and connected with a lot of threats.
The best practice would for example be an application server but my question now is, does anyone know official sources where the threats of a public databse connection is described or why it should not be done?

Comment: I think there have been enough data breaches in the news - you could probably start there and find where someone was able to query customer data from a insecure login or a poorly designed REST interface.

Comment: In addition to what bbaird said, one of the best ways to secure something is through obfuscation, specifically hide it from being known, generally speaking. If someone doesn't know something exists, they have no place to start - let alone motive in trying to find it. Again this is very high level and a generalization, of course in practice nothing is perfectly hidden, but by not exposing your database directly to the internet you reduce the size of the attack vector for your database by obscuring its presence.

Answer (score 1):

> ... does anyone know official sources where the threats of a public database connection is described or why it should not be done?

How about the Open Web Application Security Project (**OWASP**)?

Take a look at their [Database Security Cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Database_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Also, try this "[Accepted Answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before)", over on Software Engineering.